# Extract Property from Core Data in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, core-data, properties

Here is my doubt. I have a tableView which is populated by my Core Data. And each cell has a title, person, text, audio and photo. What I want is, when the user select a cell, I can present, for example the title, in a label on another view controller.

What I've been trying is to pass the info stored in the cell to a NSString, but I don't know how to extract and separate each of the parts (title, person, etc) so I can assign them properly. I already tried using substrings and comparing strings, but I couldn't do it

Just making it clearer:

Imagine a cell with a title "My Cell", a person "John Doe" and so on. When I click on it I want to get the title and set it on a label, same to the person and so on.

```
- (void)tableView:(nonnull UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(nonnull NSIndexPath *)indexPath { 
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]]; 
    VoESmallThingViewController *voe = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"VoEView"];
    voe.self.smallThing = [self.memory objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; 
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:voe animated:YES]; 
}
```

Although when I try to assign something like `self.smallThing.title = self.personTextField.text;`  doesn't work

Comment: You shouldn't extract the data from the cell, you should use the `indexPath.row` to go back to the original Core Data object

Comment: Ok. So I did this here now. `- (void)tableView:(nonnull UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(nonnull NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    VoESmallThingViewController *voe = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"VoEView"];
    voe.self.smallThing = [self.memory objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:voe animated:YES]; 
}`
Although when I try to assign something like `self.smallThing.title = self.personTextField.text;` doesn't work

Comment: You wouldn't normally use `voe.self.smallThing` as you wouldn't normally name a property `self` - `self` refers to "this object instance", so if you had a property `smallThing` in your `VoESmallThingViewController` you would just say `voe.smallThing=[self.memory objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; `

Comment: I tried it, but instead of changing the label of the VoEView it is changing the label on the tableViewCell